# Is it possible to include external file in the bundle?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, bundle

So for example instead of this:

```
bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                   "~/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"
                   ))
```

have something like:

```
bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                       $"{apiBaseUrl}/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"
                       ))
```

Provided that api endpoint is hosting that js file, which it is. (api serves like locally hosted cdn).

Right now this fails with:

> "Only application relative URLs (~/url) are allowed."

I wonder if there is a way to include the file living outside of the solution at all?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to modify the code like this.

```
bundles.UseCdn = true;   //enable CDN support
var jqueryCdnPath = $"{apiBaseUrl}/jquery-2.1.1.min.js";
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery", jqueryCdnPath).Include("~/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

In the code above, jQuery will be requested from the CDN while in release mode and the debug version of jQuery will be fetched locally in debug mode.

More info - [Bundling and Minification using CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002040#using-a-cdn)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks